# Does bases of operators on two Hilbert spaces span the operators on the tensor product of the two spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $\mathcal H_1, \mathcal H_1$ be two Hilbert spaces, $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_1\otimes\mathcal H_2$ is their [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). Let $\mathcal L(\mathcal H_1),\mathcal L(\mathcal H_2),\mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ denote operators on the three Hilbert spaces, respectively. Then
$$
\dim\mathcal L(\mathcal H)=(\dim\mathcal H)^2,
$$
and similar formulae for $\mathcal H_1,\mathcal H_2$. Besides $\dim\mathcal H=\dim\mathcal H_1\cdot\dim\mathcal H_2$, so
$$
\dim\mathcal L(\mathcal H)=\dim\mathcal L(\mathcal H_1)\cdot\dim\mathcal L(\mathcal H_2),
$$
which inspires me to check if
$$\mathcal L(\mathcal H)\stackrel?=\mathcal L(\mathcal H_1)\otimes\mathcal L(\mathcal H_2).$$

In $\mathcal L(\mathcal H_1)$, a set of tensor operators $\{\hat T_{1,q}^{(k)}\}$ can be chosen as a set of bases. And $\{\hat T^{(k)}_{2,q}\}$ for
$\mathcal L(\mathcal H_2)$.  Define

$$
\hat T_{qq'}^{(kk')}
=\hat T_{1,q}^{(k)}\hat T_{2,q'}^{(k')}.
$$

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/774003/289541), a simple case is discussed, where $\mathcal H_1,\mathcal H_2$ are irreducible and $\mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ only contains scalar operators. But I'm not able to go further. Can it be shown that $\hat T_{qq'}^{(kk')}$
are linearly independent for different $(kk'qq')$?
And what's the relationship between $\hat T_{qq'}^{(kk')}$ and $k$-order tensor operator $\hat T_q^{(k)}$ in $\mathcal H$?

Comment: As linear operators are themselves elements of vector spaces I suppose there exist entanglement of operators hence : $\exists l\in L(H_1)\otimes L(H_2) | l\neq l_1\otimes l_2$